# Cannot autowire Repository in Unit Test (Multi-module maven project)

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I'm working on a Spring Boot project right now.
I want to test custom query inside an interface with extends the `JpaRepository`. Here's the code that I can come up with :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
public class CffRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private CffRepository cffRepository;

    @Test
    public void saveCffTest() {

    }
}
```

The problem is that for `CffRepository` can't be `autowired` because No Beans of it was found. I think it's because the `CffRepository` is in different module with the MainApplication. Here's my project structure :

[image: Project structure]

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you annotate the CffRepo by @Repository annotation? when do you get the error? compile time or when you run the application?

Comment: Yes I did. When I ran the application I didn't get any error, it worked perfectly. It's just when unit testing, I can't autowire the repository and I think it's because the multi-module project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned the problem is that you don't have a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` in the classpath so the test doesn't know where to get the Spring configuration from.

One simple thing you can do is to include a TestApplication class in your `/test` dir:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

As a bonus tip you don't actually need to enable auto-configuration for all the features you are using in production. You can get away with just using the parts required for your tests.